Dataverse ServiceClient throws exception referencing PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute, return null for FetchXML query
I am using the Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client NuGet package (1.1.32) to connect to our Dynamics 365 application. This is a .NET 7 application. We have an older .NET Framework application that uses CrmServiceClient successfully, but using the new library on the newer .NET version, it has been failing querying data using the FetchXML query.
using var serviceClient = new ServiceClient(connectionString);
var id = serviceClient.GetMyUserId();
string fetchXML = @"<fetch top='5'><entity name='account'><attribute name='name' /></entity></fetch>";
var queryResult = serviceClient.GetEntityDataByFetchSearch(fetchXML);

What is working are the first two lines. I can can connect to Dynamics, and the call to GetMyUserId() is successful, but using the FetchXML syntax (using an example from learn.microsoft.com), returns null.
When examining the ServiceClient object, I see there is a value in the LastException property:
"Could not load type 'System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethodAttribute' from assembly 'System.Web, Version 4.0.0.0..."

I have attempted to add the System.Web DLL by using the "Add COM References" in Visual Studio, but that has failed, probably because of some serious .NET compatibility issues between version 4 and 7. And I don't know if this error is the reason for the FetchXML query failing or not - perhaps it's related or perhaps not.

So this question is really two:

Is my syntax correct for returning data from Dynamics using FetchXML? I'm also open to another way to get the data
If that error is related, how can I go about fixing it?


I never did find a solution to this problem - the connection to Dynamics CRM always failed. What I did to get around this is imported the data into our Azure SQL database and then was able to pull it from Azure into our web application without an issue.
